# Get all items from a list without referring to them one by one

Tags: 2013, jsom, sharepoint-fields

I would like to know if there is a way to get all items without referring one by one like I have done in my code? This code returns nothing.

```
function onS() {
    var listString = "";
     var Enum = listItems.getEnumerator();
       while (Enum.moveNext()) {
     var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
    var data = currentItem.get_fieldValues();
    listString += currentItem.Title;
    }
    $("#items").html(listString);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. You want to build your `listString` variable without having to enumerate through the collection of items? If so, why?

Comment: I have tried in many different ways but nothing works

Comment: I did but it returns nothing

Comment: Sorry, it is "data.Title". The whole JSON response resides in data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to get the JSON response of all field values use get_fieldValues() method

```
var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
 var data = currentItem.get_fieldValues();
```

it returns the keyvalue pair JSON data like

```
{'Title':'Title Value',
 'ID':'ID value',
 'ColumnInternaName':'ColumnValue',
  .....
  .....}
```

you can get the title by

```
data.Title
```

Id by

```
data.ID
```

etc...

if you load items using 'Include' like

```
context.load(listItems,'Include(Title,ID)')
```

Then the JSON only contains the data of Title and ID

Comment: not Title(), it is just Title, it is not a function

Comment: what error did you get? update your code in Question

Comment: I have updated my code , take a look please

Comment: answered below you question

Answer (score 1):

I am mostly using REST to get all items from a list like the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function() {    

                    // Rest Call
                    var requestUri = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('News')/items";

                        $.ajax({
                            url: requestUri,
                            type: "GET",
                            headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                            success: function (data) {
                                $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item){
                                    var title = item.Title;
                                    var description = item.Description;
                                    var pictureURLDesc = item.PictureURL.Description;
                                    var pictureURL = item.PictureURL.Url;   
                                    var linkDesc = item.Link.Description;
                                    var linkURL = item.Link.Url;    
                                    var currentItemID = item.ID;                

                                    try 
                                    {   
                                        // Slice description
                                        if (description.length > 102){
                                            llength = description.slice(0, 102) + " ...";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            llength = description;
                                        }
                                    } 
                                    catch ( err ) 
                                    { 
                                        alert( err ); 
                                    }               

                                    // Check News item   
                                    alert("Item Nr: " + currentItemID + "Title: " + title + "Description: " + llength);                 
                                })
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("Error getting items");
                            }                     
                        });   
});                              
</script>
```